Power BI - Azure DevOps Git integration
I created a Power BI project (.pbip) in Power BI desktop and pushed the files to an Azure DevOps repository. I need to link the dev branch of the repo to a workspace in PowerBI service. Both Power BI and the repository are within the same tenant.
In PowerBI service, I have a premium per user workspace, fabric features are enabled, git integration at tenant level is enabled.
When I access workspace settings -> git integration I get the following:

Although there are no specific technical details in the UI itself, if I inspect the page and look at the failed request, I see the following error:
Endpoint: /metadata/git/organizations?gitProviderType=AzureDevOps&workspaceId=...
Error: AADSTS50158: External security challenge not satisfied. User will be redirected to another page or authentication provider to satisfy additional authentication challenges.
I read that this error might be related to MFA which my organization requires. We do not want to disable any of the existing security policies.
There is no redirect happening whatsoever and since no error is displayed in the UI itself, I am not even sure the error above is the real problem I should investigate.
Any idea how to fix this or if there is another viable alternative to achieve the same result?
Is there a way to use a service principal to connect to the git repo instead of my user account?

According to the error message, your Azure tenant has MFA or Conditional Access policy enabled. To access any resources connected to the tenant, the MFA or Conditional Access policy must be satisfied.
To integrate your Power BI with Azure DevOps, you can create a repo in Azure DevOps, clone it to VS Code and then save your project into the local repo folder. See the detailed steps from Power BI Desktop projects Git integration.

I followed the steps in the article you provided. I got stuck on the Git Integration screen from the workspace settings.  When I try to connect my git repository with the pbip project to the PowerBI workspace, I am not able to select the organization and repo and that's probably because of MFA.
Could you please give more detail on what you mean by: 'To access any resources connected to the tenant, the MFA or Conditional Access policy must be satisfied.' How could I make sure this is satisfied? I don't get a login popup for the MFA flow to happen.

In the doc shared by me, a local repo is set up in VS Code. After you commit all the changes to the local repo, you can run git remote add origin <URL for Azure Git repo> and git push -u origin master to connect to Azure repo.  Check MFA and CAP from Set up your users with multifactor authentication and Setting up Conditional Access.
